# IN clause with jooq and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I have the following code which works fine:

```
fun <T> createComparisonOperator(field: Field<T>, value: T, op: String): Condition {
    return when(op) {
        "eq" -> field.eq(DSL.inline(value))
        else -> throw Exception("No Op)
      }
}
```

Now what I want to do is test for membership in an array and I do something like:

```
fun<T> createMembershipOperator(field: Field<T>, value: Collection<T>, op: String): Condition {
      return when(op) {
        "in" -> field.`in`(DSL.inline(value))
        else -> throw Exception("No op")
      }
    }
```

The membership test is called as:

```
val wrappedValue = listOf("100")
val sqlField = DSL.field(column, SQLDataType.VARCHAR)
return createMembershipOperator<String>(sqlField, wrappedValue, op)
```

It does not fail but does not return any data.

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```kotlin
"in" -> field.`in`(value.map(DSL::inline))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!